# Spring boot application /actuator/refresh return 404

Tags: java, spring-boot

Facts:

- SpringBoot version: 2.5.6
- actuator dependency added to pom.xml
- in application.yaml the endpoints are enabled:

  management:
  endpoints:
  web:
  exposure:
  include: '*'

If I make a `curl -X POST localhost:8080/actuator/refresh` getting the following response:

```
"timestamp":"2022-01-20T13:32:48.516+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not
Found","path":"/actuator/refresh"}
```

I have checked all posts about this topic and tried out all possible solutions but untill now no success. Where do I fail?

PS: `curl localhost:8080/actuator/health` is returning a valid response.

```
{ "status": "UP" }
```

**EDIT**

I found out that /actuator/refresh is working with the following spring boot version and below.

With newer version until now no success

```
   <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
```

**EDIT 2**:

Spring boot over 2.4.0 has no `refresh` endpoint

**EDIT 3**: with following deps is

```
spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-fabric8-config
Spring Cloud Starter Config
```

allows all endpoints

**EDIT 4**: actuator is a spring cloud properties so, it should be available its dependency

Comment: The refresh endpoint is part of Spring Cloud. Are you using Spring Cloud in your application?

Comment: Yes, I want to integrate spring cloud, but getting 404 error

Comment: Got same issue. Update spring boot from 2.3 to 2.5.4, then actuator/health start to return 404.  
how did you resolve the issue ?

Comment: Make sure your spring boot version and the dependency version. Check out spring cloud starter deps.

Comment: try to align yml configuration correctly

Answer (score 0):

1. The documentation says that all endpoints are available by default except **shutdown**

> By default, all endpoints except for shutdown are enabled. To
> configure the enablement of an endpoint, use its
> management.endpoint..enabled property. The following example
> enables the shutdown endpoint:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.enabling

2. The refresh endpoint is not mentioned into the list of endpoints https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.exposing
3. If you want to have new custom endpoint, spring actuator provide a way to do it:

   ```
    @Component
    @Endpoint(id="custom-endpoint")
    public class CustomEndPoint {
        @ReadOperation
        public CustomData customEndpoint() {
            // you have to define this class CustomData
            CustomData data = new CustomData();
            // ... set some attributes
            return data;
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: essentially I am trying to https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reloading-properties#reloading-cloud

Comment: @Rzw Razvan interestingly /actuator/refresh is working with spring boot version 2.3.12 and below

Comment: I assume that /actuator/refresh is working only with spring-cloud since it is used to refresh application configurations without restarting the application (also you have to use a config server)
You have an example here from spring.io https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/